# Facebook API - permissions error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Anyone know what is the reason for this Facebook API error?
This is appearing sometimes while user is posting by /feed call.

```
"error":{"message":"Permissions error", "type":"FacebookApiException", "code":200, "error_subcode":1376025
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting to a user's wall is not a default permission and as such you're probably trying to post without first checking they have granted to permission to do so.  If you're finding multiple users are causing this error, consider only asking for permission when your app needs it.  From [the Facebook Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0):

> For cases where someone has granted some permissions but not others,
>   only prompt for missing permissions at the point at which they are
>   needed. For example, if your app posts stories to Facebook, only
>   request publish_actions when they ask to publish a story.

Alas, I could be way off - but that's what I think is happening based on your description.  There isn't much else that could be causing that if it works sometimes and not others, given your error message is an exception from the Facebook API itself.

Comment: It's not the situation because the user sometimes manage to make these calls.

Comment: Do you know how often that user is logging in/out?  Do you know whether it's the same user or multiple users?

Comment: Anyone knows what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a test account along with the API for testing on Facebook and you are trying to post Facebook content such as a link to a video that has been uploaded to Facebook, then you will get this error.

In my case I was using the API to post this video: https://www.facebook.com/LADbible/videos/the-turkey-whisperer/4699159626797857/ to my test user accounts facebook page and I was getting that error. When I used a different link facebook allowed the post to go through.

This may not be a fix for you but maybe for anyone else coming across this permissions error.