# facebook graph api photo post suddenly started giving permission error

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social-facebook

I am posting photo on facebook page using facebook graph api 2.2.
I am using spring social for the same. The application was working properly out of a sudden the photo posts started giving error few days back saying permission error on posts with a photo . Non photo posts are properly posted on pages.

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
    Resource resource = null;
    resource = new FileSystemResource("xyz.jpg");   
    facebook.pageOperations().postPhoto(acId, "photos", resource, "TEST POST");
```

The error that i am receiving from facebook graph api is .

```
{"error":{"message":"Permissions error","type":"FacebookApiException","code":200,"error_subcode":1366002}}
```

Comment: you may want to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227713/facebook-api-permissions-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using 
facebook.pageOperations().postPhoto(acId,albumId, resource, "TEST POST");

The second parameter is supposed to be the Album ID. When I place the call to this method with Album ID of the page, it actually works.

I think in your earlier code were passing in a name instead of album id.

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
Resource resource = null;
resource = new FileSystemResource("xyz.jpg"); 
facebook.pageOperations().postPhoto(acId, "photos", resource, "TEST POST")
```

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your app has manage_pages permission by going to 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=xxxxxx

You can also confirm that you are a page admin for the page using spring social =>
facebook.pageOperations().isPageAdmin("pageId")

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out the solution. Seems like there is an issue with spring social due to some recent changes in facebook graph api .

The pageoperations.postPhoto method fails if we pass objectId as first parameter and photos as second.

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
Resource resource = null;
resource = new FileSystemResource("xyz.jpg");   
facebook.pageOperations().postPhoto(acId, "photos", resource, "TEST POST");
```

The solution i found was to modify the above code like this

```
    facebook.pageOperations().postPhoto(acId, acId, resource, "TEST POST");
```

this seems to be a bug in spring social i tested with spring social 2 jars and the reason is the final url on which post happens is not formed correctly internally.

Hope this helps someone else struggling with sudden break in posting photos on page

Answer (score 0):

error_subcode 1366002 also shows up when you try to post photos to an album that have close to 1000 photos (which is the maximum).

You don't get any message indicating this.